# BASH: Error with read command

Tags: bash, unix

Can someone tell me why I am getting errors, and explain the best way to go about the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
SFTP=1
SSH=2
SCP=3
echo "Starting Seedbox Macro"
echo " . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
echo "Type 1 for SFTP, type 2 for SSH, type 3 for SCP"
read $sftp
if [sftp]
then echo "Starting SFTP"; 
sftp -P 78 192.168.100.101;
fi
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: For read, you want to specify the name of a variable, not the value. Remove the `$` and use `read sftp`.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use the `select` command to avoid all that boilerplate code.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting Seedbox Macro"
echo " . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
select mycmd in sftp ssh scp quit; do
  case "$mycmd" in
    sftp)
      sftp -P 78 192.168.100.101
      ;;
    ssh)
      ssh ...
      ;;
    scp)
      scp ...
      ;;
    quit)
      exit
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Ohh, that `select` is nifty, never noticed it before. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `read` is a variable name, so it should be:

```
read sftp
```

`$` is used when you want the expansion of a variable to bs substituted, e.g.

```
if [ "$sftp" = 1 ]
then ...
```

If you're asking for a choice from a menu, you might want to consider using the `select` command instead of `read`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
read sftp
if [ "$sftp" -eq "1" ]
```

etc...

Comment: what does the argument -eq do?

Comment: @user2421618: `-eq` performs numeric comparison.

Comment: Notice also that the spaces are significant. `[` is the name of a command (also known as `test`) so you need a space before its first srgument.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `$' while using read in a variable, so you better put it something like this:

```
read sftp
if [ "$sftp" -eq $SFTP ] 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Two issues:

1. `read $sftp` should be `read sftp`.
2. `if` loop should be

   `if [ "$sftp" -eq 1 ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` command to make process. I think it is the `BEST` way.

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
    do
        echo -n "Please, type!"
        read ANSWER

        case $ANSWER in
        sftp)
            SFTP CODE GOES HERE...
            break
            ;;

        ssh)
            SSH CODE GOES HERE...
            exit
            ;;

        scp)
            SCP CODE GOES HERE...
            exit
            ;;

        *) echo "Please enter only sftp, ssh or scp!"
        esac
    done
echo "Process done!"
```

You can add different cases instead of "sftp", "ssh" or "scp". Or you can add more cases after these 3 cases.